# Error 302 al implementar Spring Security

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf, spring-security

estoy intentando implementar Spring Security en una aplicación de registro de usuarios con roles en BBDD, y una implementación de login con autentificación.

Al pulsar en el botón Login, me devuelve un código de error 302:
[image: Formulario - Código de error 302]

No estoy recibiendo ningún error más, ni por consola ni nada.. Y es lo que me esta dando mas dolores de cabeza.

Os dejo por aquí las clases que estoy implementando, si hiciera falta alguna más comentarme, gracias!

**SecurityConfig: Configuración Spring Security**

```
import com.example.demospringsecurity.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static com.example.demospringsecurity.core.Constants.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder, UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) throws Exception {
        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
                .and().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configureMvcSecurity(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(
                authorizeRequest ->
                {
                    try {
                        authorizeRequest.requestMatchers(LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/new-user").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/home/screenUser").hasRole(USER_ROLE)
                                .requestMatchers("/home/screenAdmin").hasRole(ADMIN_ROLE)
                                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable()
                                .formLogin()
                                .loginPage(LOGIN_URL)
                                .defaultSuccessUrl(LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL)
                                .failureUrl("/ok");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
        ).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl: Clase que implementa UserDetailsService**

```
package com.example.demospringsecurity.service.impl;

import com.example.demospringsecurity.domain.User;

import com.example.demospringsecurity.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userService.findUserByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario/contraseña incorrectos");
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));

        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
    }

    public UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                true, true, true, true, authorities);
    }
}
```

**User: Clase del usuario**

```
package com.example.demospringsecurity.domain;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.*;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String role;

}
```

**index.html: Donde estoy realizando el inicio de sesión y el registro**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pantalla principal</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Registro de usuarios</h2>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/new-user}" th:object="${user}" method="post">

    <label>Usuario</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{username}">

    <label>Contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" th:field="*{password}">

    <select th:field="*{role}">
        <option th:value="admin">Admin</option>
        <option th:value="user">User</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <br>

    <button type="submit">Registrarse</button>
</form>
<br>
<br>

<label th:text="${messageRegister}"></label>

<h2>Inicio de sesión</h2>
<form th:action="@{/login}"  method="post">

    <label>Usuario</label>
    <input type="text">

    <label>Contraseña</label>
    <input type="password">

    <br>
    <br>

    <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTTP 302 no es un error, es un redirect

Comment: Y como consigo que no haga ese redirect? O por que ocurre?

Comment: La lógica de tu despliegue está redirigiendo desde `/login` hacia `/index`. Puedes verlo en los encabezados de la respuesta. No sé si es que ya estás autenticado :)